# Anti-Aliasing LibreOffice Writer 4.x Under Windows

Tags: libreoffice, anti-aliasing

I have the 4.x version of LibreOffice installed on Ubuntu and its Writer renders the text so smoothly, but nothing like that is under Windows.

I am using Windows 8.1 Update 64-bit, and tried to install different releases of 4.x LibreOffice with no luck.

Edit: I have the anti-aliasing option check.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I disabled OpenGL for all rendering at Tools>Options>View, and everything became so smooth.

Comment: Can you explain in more details how you did that?

Comment: not quite sure how this would help with antialiasing

Answer (score 0):

Enable Clear Type under Control Panel -> Appearance and Personalization -> Fonts

Answer (score 0):

For me the following helped.

You may change Compatibility setting of the SOFFICE.exe file:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenOffice 4\program\soffice.exe Right click ->
>   Properties -> Change high DPI settings -> High DPI scaling override -
>   check "Override high DPI scaling bahvior. Application"

Windows 7/8

OpenOffice forum:

> by BurleighBill » Mon Nov 25, 2013 7:59 am  Right click the file,
>   choose Properties, select the Compatibility tab, and check the box to
>   "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings." Now Open Office is
>   super crisp!